# How do I get the diagonal values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to write a program that takes the diagonal values of an 3 rows with 3 columns.

The array itself is:

```
[4, 2, 5] 
[1, 8, 3] 
[4, 3, 9]
```

... and the output is supposed to be:

```
[4, 8, 9]
```

or the other way around:

```
[5, 8, 4]
```

I have this so far:

```
var DIAGONAL_TOP_LEFT_BOTTOM_RIGHT = 0;
var DIAGONAL_BOTTOM_LEFT_TOP_RIGHT = 1;

function start(){
    var grid = new Grid(3, 3);
    grid.initFromArray([
    [4, 2, 5], // 0th row
    [1, 8, 3], // 1st row
    [4, 3, 9] // 2nd row]);
    var diagonal =
    }




function getDiagonal(grid, whichDiagonal){
    var diagonalList = [];
    for(var col = 0; col < grid.getCols(); col++){
        for(var row = 0; row < grid.getRows(); row++){
            println(col);
            var cur = grid.get(row,col);
            println(cur);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not too sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I've posted my answer which very simply accounts for both scenarios and also validates that the parameter being used is a valid matrix (same number of rows and columns across all arrays). Take a look when you have a chance :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` - the second parameter is the index, so this script finds the first value in the first array, the second in the second and so on...

```js
const matrix = [
    [4, 2, 5], 
    [1, 8, 3], 
    [4, 3, 9]];

console.log('↘️', 
    matrix.map((a, i) => a[i]));
console.log('↗️', 
    [...matrix].reverse().map((a, i) => a[i]));
```

Comment: Forgot to add some variables at the top of the code.

`var DIAGONAL_TOP_LEFT_BOTTOM_RIGHT = 0;
var DIAGONAL_BOTTOM_LEFT_TOP_RIGHT = 1;

function start(){
'code goes here'
}`

Comment: @sendmeng if you want to go diagonally the other way you could just add `.reverse()` to go through the arrays backwards

Comment: @Keith except that `.reverse()` will also mutate the original array

Comment: @sendmeng You could either use `.slice().reverse()` to take a shallow copy and then reverse the array, or you could get the inverted index using `[array.length-index-1]`

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell or do `[...matrix].reverse()` there are bunch of ways to do it

Comment: @Keith yes, that would be a good way to do it as well

Answer (score 1):

The function `diag()` will return the diagonal of any 2D matrix:

```js
const arr=[[4, 2, 5],
   [1, 8, 3],[4, 3, 9]];

const diag=a=>a.map((v,i)=>v[i]);

console.log(diag(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

We'll first want to check to make sure the matrix is a perfect square (same length of nested arrays, as the number of items per array).

The `isValidMatrix()` function I added checks to make sure the matrix array is a valid array, that every child is also a valid array with the same length as their parent matrix.

After that, I added two separate functions `getDiag1()` and `getDiag2()`. The first function maps each nested array to whichever element therein has the same index as its nested array. In other words, it will grab the first item from the first array, the second from the second, and so on. We do so like this: `row[i]`

Conversely, the second function will grab the last array item from the first array, the second to last array item from the second array, and so on. We do so like this: `row[row.length-i-1]`

```js
let matrix = [[4, 2, 5],
              [1, 8, 3],
              [4, 3, 9]];

const isValidMatrix = matrix => Array.isArray(matrix) && matrix.every(row => Array.isArray(row) && row.length === matrix.length)
const getDiag1 = matrix => isValidMatrix(matrix) && matrix.map((row,i) => row[i]);
const getDiag2 = matrix => isValidMatrix(matrix) && matrix.map((row,i) => row[row.length-i-1]);

console.log(getDiag1(matrix), getDiag2(matrix));
```